# How to debug Wake-on-LAN

Tags: windows-10, raspberry-pi, wireshark, wake-on-lan

I have a windows PC and I enabled the Wake-on-LAN feature in my ethernet network adapter and BIOS settings.

I'm trying to send a wol packet to this windows PC by using the MAC address from my raspberry pi 4. But nothing happens.

I've installed wireshark on my macbook but I don't see any traffic if I enable the filter to wol protocol

How can I further debug this?